# Implementing Exponential Moving Average in C++

Tags: c++, math

I am developing a small trading robot as an exercise. He receives stock prices day after day (represented as iterations).

Here's what my `Trade` class looks like:

```
class   Trade
{
private:
  int                   capital_;
  int                   days_; // Total number of days of available stock prices                                       
  int                   daysInTrading_; // Increments as days go by.                                                   
  std::list<int>        stockPrices_; // Contains stock prices day after day.                                          
  int                   currentStock_; // Current stock we are dealing with.                                           
  int                   lastStock_; // Last stock dealt with                                                           
  int                   trend_; // Either {-1; 0; 1} depending on the trend.                                           
  int                   numOfStocks_; // Number of stocks in our possession
  int                   EMA_; // Exponential Moving Average                                                            
  int                   lastEMA_; // Last EMA                                                                          

public:
    // functions
};
```

As you can see from my last two attributes, I wish to implement an Exponential Moving Average as part of a Trend Following Algorithm.

But I think I didn't quite understand how to implement it; here's my `calcEMA` function that simply calculates the `EMA`:

```
int     Trade::calcEMA()
{
  return ((this->currentStock_ - this->lastEMA_
           * (2/(this->daysInTrading_ + 1)))
          + this->lastEMA_);
}
```

But when my stock values (passed in a file) are like such:

```
1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1400, 1300, 1200, 1100, 1000
```

As to make sure my EMA makes sense, and well... it does not !

Where did I go wrong on the operation?

Aditionally, what value should I give `lastEMA` if it's the first time I call `calcEMA`?

Comment: `2/(this->daysInTrading_ + 1)` -- This truncates since it is integer division.  Is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are missing a parentheses in the "calcEMA" function. How about breaking the expression up into smaller expressions with temporary variables to hold intermediate results like this?

```
int Trade::calcEMA()
{       
   auto mult = 2/(timePeriod_ + 1);
   auto rslt = (currentStock_ - lastEMA_) * mult + lastEMA_;      
   return rslt;
}
```

Also, as user PaulMcKenzie pointed out in the comment on your question, you are using the integer to do floating point calculation.  You may consider using float or double to avoid possible truncation.

Here are my suggestions:

An EMA like yours is defined for a time period.  While  `daysInTrading` is less or equal to `timePeriod`, `lastEMA` should be set to a normal average.

Once `daysInTrading` is greater than your `timePeriod` you can start calling your "calcEMA" function with initialized `lastEMA`.

Please, remember to update `lastEMA` after each call to the "calcEMA" function.

Here is my code for you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

// calculate a moving average
double calcMA (double previousAverage, 
    unsigned int previousNumDays, 
    double newStock) {
   auto rslt = previousNumDays * previousAverage + newStock;
   return rslt / (previousNumDays + 1.0);
}

// calculate an exponential moving average
double calcEMA (double previousAverage, 
    int timePeriod, 
    double newStock) {
   auto mult = 2.0 / (timePeriod + 1.0);
   auto rslt = (newStock - previousAverage) * mult + previousAverage;
   return rslt;
}

class Trade {
   unsigned int timePeriod_ = 5;
   double lastMA_ = 0.0;
   std::list<double> stockPrices_;
  
  public:     
   void addStock (double newStock) {
      stockPrices_.push_back(newStock);
      auto num_days = stockPrices_.size(); 

      if (num_days <= timePeriod_)
         lastMA_ = calcMA(lastMA_, num_days - 1, newStock);
      else
         lastMA_ = calcEMA(lastMA_, num_days - 1, newStock);
   }

   double getAverage() const { return lastMA_; }
};


// ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----    
int main() {
   std::vector<double> stocks =
     {1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 
         1400, 1300, 1200, 1100, 1000};

   Trade trade;
   for (auto stock : stocks)
      trade.addStock(stock);

   std::cout << "Average: " << trade.getAverage() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The operation is wrong, as you noticed.

***Disclaimer*** I got this algorithm from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), and as such might no be accurate. [Here](http://www.cis.umac.mo/~fstasp/paper/jetwi2011.pdf) (page 3) might be a better one, but I can't judge, I never used those algorithms and so have no idea what I'm talking about :)

> `c(EMA) = y(EMA) + a * (c(price) - y(EMA))`
>
> - `c(EMA)` is current EMA
> - `y(EMA)` is previous EMA
> - `a` is some "random" value between 0 and 1
> - `c(price)` is current price

But you did almost the same thing:

> `c(EMA) = (c(price) - y(EMA) * b) + y(EMA)`

I don't know why you did `2 / daysInTrading_ + 1`, but this will not always be a value between 0 and 1 (actually, it might even be most of the time 0, because those are all intergers).

You put a parenthesis at the wrong place (after `b`, and not after `y(EMA)`).

So the operation will now look like this:

**`lastEMA_ + 0.5 * (currentStock_ - lastEMA_)`**

---

For the first `lastEMA_`, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average):

> S<sub>1</sub> is undefined. S<sub>1</sub> may be initialized in a number of different ways, most commonly by setting S<sub>11</sub> [*First element in the list*], though other techniques exist, such as setting S<sub>1</sub> to an average of the first 4 or 5 observations.
>
> The importance of the S<sub>1</sub> initialisations effect on the resultant moving average depends on α; smaller α values make the choice of S<sub>1</sub> relatively more important than larger α values, since a higher α discounts older observations faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have read the following paper: http://www.cis.umac.mo/~fstasp/paper/jetwi2011.pdf about Trend Following Algorithms and saw the principle on page 3. Also, what value should your a take? Truly a random value between 0 and 1 or is there an explanation behind it?

Comment: @ChristopherK. I didn't mean random as in random, but in whatever you choose. It depends really on what you want to have. See the quote (I use `a`, Wikipedia uses alpha)

Comment: @ChristopherK. Use the algorithm you linked, it might be more accurate than wikipedia :)

Answer (score 3):

There are generally two accepted forms of EMA.

The traditional:

```
m = 2/(1+n)                               // where n >= 1
EMA = m * currentPrice + (1-m) * previousEMA

rf the Wilder:

m = 1/n                                   // where n >= 1
EMA Wilder = m * currentPrice + (1-m) * previousEMA
```