# Coding the P&Q rule using Exponential Moving Average in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am developing a small trading robot using C++ as an exercise. He will receive at first basic information such as our capital, and day to day stock values (represented as iterations).

Here is my `Trade` class:

```
class   Trade
{
private:
  int                   capital_;
  int                   days_; // Total number of days of available stock prices                                       
  int                   daysInTrading_; // Increments as days go by.                                                   
  std::list<int>        stockPrices_; // Contains stock prices day after day.                                          
  int                   currentStock_; // Current stock we are dealing with.                                           
  int                   lastStock_; // Last stock dealt with                                                           
  int                   trend_;                                          
  int                   numOfStocks_; // Amount of stock options in our possession
  float                 EMA_; // Exponential Moving Average                                                            
  float                 lastEMA_; // Last EMA                                                                          

public:
// functions                              
};
```

As you can tell from the last two attributes, I am using the Exponential Moving Average principle with a Trend Following Algorithm.

I've read about it through this paper http://www.cis.umac.mo/~fstasp/paper/jetwi2011.pdf (mainly on page 3) and wish to implement the Pseudo code they have shared with us; it goes like such:

```
Repeat  
Compute EMA(T)  
If no position opened 
   If EMA(T) >= P
      If trend is going up 
        Open a long position 
      Else if trend is going down  
        Open a short position 
Else if any position is opened 
   If EMA(¬T) >= Q
     Close position 
   If end of market  
     Close all opened position 
Until market close
```

And here's how I've gone about it so far:

```
void    Trade::scanTrend()
{                 
  if (this->numOfStocks_ == 0) // If no position is opened
    {
      this->EMA_ = this->calcEMA(); // Calculates the EMA
      if (this->EMA_ >= this->currentStock_) //  If EMA(T) >= P
        {
          if (this->EMA_ > this->lastEMA_) // If trend is going up
            // Trend is going up, open a long position
          else if (this->EMA_ < this->lastEMA_) // If trend is going down
            // Trend is going down, open a short position                                                                                  
        }
    }
  else // Else if any position is opened 
    {
      this->EMA_ = this->calcEMA();
      // How may I represent closing positions?
    }
  this->lastEMA_ = this->EMA_;
}
```

My problem comes from not understanding the act of "opening" and "closing" a position. Does it have anything to do with buying or selling stock? Does what I have so far seem fitting with the pseudo code?

Comment: Is this a different question from http://stackoverflow.com/q/37300684?

Comment: Absolutely, after solving the first issue with calculating EMA's (thanks to Rakete1111) I am now focused on the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

P and Q are thresholds or EMA variations between two dates in that case.

P will be the variation between the first observation and the current one. If P is positive then you can assume the trend is up and down for P<0.

Q is a variation of EMA too but used to know when to close a position, it is the difference between the highest (lowest) EMA value from the first observation and the current one for an up (down) trend.